# How to store a constant in a variable?

Tags: c++

I have a constant like this:

```
const int TEST1 = 3;
```

How can I correctly store it for later use like so?

```
int hhh = TEST1;
```

Reason for doing this is that I have 8 constants and I need to selet one of them depending on variable input.

I don't get any errors when doing it this way but if I later refer to the hhh variable it doesnt seem to have the correct value.

Comment: What you have there should work. Perhaps some other code is modifying `hhh` between when you assign it and when you use it?

Comment: That is the correct way to store the constant in a variable; your issue, however, lies elsewhere, and we require code to solve it.

Comment: You're not storing a reference to the constant. You're storing the value of the constant. You can still modify `hhh` because `hhh` is not constant...maybe I'm confused by what you are saying is the issue?

Comment: Will check my code and get back in a little while.

Comment: Why should it act like constant?

Comment: I mean act like a value of a constant, will edit Q as it is unclear.

Comment: My problem seems to be unrelated to the question I asked. There was no issue with setting variable to constant's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const int TEST1 = 3;
```

Is the correct way to store a const.
However if later you set a different variable to the TEST1

```
int iii = TEST1; //iii is not const, but TEST1 still is
```